# WPF ContentPresenter doesn't work with single Entry in ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, resourcedictionary, contentpresenter

I have a curious problem with my ContentPresenter. In my standard WPF application I have a "TestView", a "TestViewModel", a "MainWindowView" and a "MainWindowViewModel". 
The MainWindowView contains a ContentPresenter, which content is bound to a ViewModelProperty of the MainWindowViewModel:

```
<ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                  Height="Auto"
                  Width="Auto"
                  Content="{Binding CurrentContentViewModel}" />
```

And the ViewModel:

```
private IViewModel _currentContentViewModel;
public IViewModel CurrentContentViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return  _currentContentViewModel;
    }
    set
    {
        _currentContentViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }
```

The TestView is bound to the TestViewModel in my App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:TestViewModel}">
            <view:TestView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

When I now assign an instance of the TestViewModel to the CurrentContentViewModel, the ContentPresenter shows the class name of the TestViewModel:

```
MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
MainWindowView mainWindowView = new MainWindowView(mainWindowViewModel);

TestViewModel testViewModel = new TestViewModel();

mainWindowView.Show();
mainWindowViewModel.CurrentContentViewModel = testViewModel;
```

How did I fix the problem? I added an empty style tag, an SolidColorBrush definition or something else to my ResourceDictionary:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:TestViewModel}">
            <view:TestView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBrushDummy" Color="HotPink"/>

    </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

Now is everything fine and the ContentPresenter show the TestView.

And now my question: **Why?**

**Edit:**

I've made a new SampleProject and reproduced the error. The problem occurs, when I started to use the OnStartup method of my App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    MainWindowView mainWindowView = new MainWindowView(mainWindowViewModel);

    TestViewModel testViewModel = new TestViewModel();

    mainWindowView.Show();
    mainWindowViewModel.CurrentContentViewModel = testViewModel;
}
```

My TestView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ErrorSample.TestView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ErrorSample"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450"
         d:DesignWidth="800"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:TestViewModel}">
<Grid Background="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

My TestViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Text { get; } = "Sample Text";
}
```

And my MainWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IViewModel _currentContentViewModel;

    public IViewModel CurrentContentViewModel
    {
        get => _currentContentViewModel;
        set
        {
            _currentContentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: **Q1** : Why is the `CurrentContentViewModel` set as a `Content`? That is not MvvM! `CurrentContentViewModel` should be the `DataContext` of a control. **Q2** : Your code is very complicated could it not be simplified? Also we don't have any information on how you use the `MainWindowView`?  **Q3** : Also how does the `TestView` look like?

Comment: I wanted to make a new simple application without my project structure, but the error is not there anymore. I try to reproduce it by adding code from the project above. Why isn't it MVVM?